# Android TV game development

Tags: android, libgdx

Anybody develop games for Android TV? Especially with libGDX?

I would like to know what game controllers Android TV uses? And whether we can use libGDX to control the game controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Obviously. http://www.android.com/tv/ showcases a few games that are available. I assume that they are using the same channels that they would use to make a game for a phone or a tablet, based on the pictures and a little familiarity with the SDK.

Although I don't use libGDX that much, I assume that because it rides on the Android SDK, it shouldn't be too hard to tweak your game for TV.

Also, I assume that any game controllers you can use with Android you can use on the TV.

Comment: "Any game controllers you can use with Android you can use on the TV" - I have MOGA controllers, can it work? Can Ouya works? I would like to know what game controllers work with TV.